# Immutability and circular references

Tags: oop, functional-programming, immutability, circular-reference

I'll use python for the example code but I'm sure this problem can be reproduced on the majority of programming languages.

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None, prev=None, next=None):
        self._value = value
        self._prev = prev
        self._next = next

    def with_value(self, value):
        return Node(value=value, prev=self._prev, next=self._next)

    def with_prev(self, prev):
        return Node(value=self._value, prev=prev, next=self._next)

    def with_next(self, next):
        return Node(value=self._value, prev=self._prev, next=next)
```

So basically, this'd allow us to create a `Node` instance like this:

```
node = Node()
      .with_value(30)
      .with_prev(
         Node()
         .with_value(25))
      .with_next(
         Node()
         .with_value(35))
```

The problem here is that each `Node` needs to have a reference of the previous and next nodes, so actually we need to fix these `with_prev` and `with_next` methods:

```
def with_prev(self, prev):
    prev = prev.with_next(self)
    return Node(value=self._value, prev=prev, next=self._next)
```

But this isn't right... 
The previous node now has a `next` reference to an instance that has been thrown away.

If I try to do it the other way around I have a similar problem:

```
def with_prev(self, prev):
    node = Node(value=self._value, prev=prev, next=self._next)
    prev = prev.with_next(node)
    return node
```

My `node` instance now has an incorrect/stale `prev` reference.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to call `with_next()` or `with_prev()` in the `Node` constructor basically, where you can pass `self` (even before it is completely initialised).

Comment: You also will want to provide an efficient creation method. Calling `with_next` essentially creates a complete new list, so if you simply repeatedly append a node you'll have a quadratic complexity

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by changing your `next` and `prev` references to thunks that lazily evaluate to the actual references.  This is tricky to get right, though, and requires initialization of the entire list at once.

An easier way is to just store a singly-linked list, then use a [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) to keep track of the back links when you traverse it.  If you need to be able to traverse starting from the tail of the list, just store two lists, one with forward links and one with back.